# How to stop onActivityCreated of a parent Fragment to call when i initialise an extends Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Basically, i created new Fragment by Extended from the other fragment because i just want to override some method but still keep using a lot of it.

Original Fragment

```
public class RestaurantListFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, " :Original :onActivityCreated");
    }
}
```

Extends fragment.

```
public class RestaurantByFoodListFragment extends RestaurantListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, " :Modify :onActivityCreated");
    }
}
```

So when i call the extends fragment from `PagerAdapter` like this

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, " :getItem");
                restaurantByFoodListFragment = new RestaurantByFoodListFragment();
                restaurantByFoodListFragment.setFoodId(this.foodId);
                return restaurantByFoodListFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Seem like `onActivityCreated` inside both of the fragment getting called (i just only want the extends one to call)

This is my log.

```
Res List Fragment:  :Original :onActivityCreated
Res By Food Fragment:  :Modify :onActivityCreated
Res List Fragment:  :Original :onActivityCreated
Res By Food Fragment:  :Modify :onActivityCreated
```

So is that possible for only trigger `onActivityCreated` inside the extended Fragment (`RestaurantByFoodListFragment`) without trigger the original Fragment (`RestaurantListFragment`)?

Thanks!

Comment: You explicitly trigger it by calling `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);`, but why does it matter?

Comment: Because there is some function that i dont want to call inside the original Fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by changing your classes as follows:

```
public class RestaurantListFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        onActivityCreatedInternal();
    }

    protected void onActivityCreatedInternal() {
        Log.d(TAG, " :Original :onActivityCreated");
    }
}
```

```
public class RestaurantByFoodListFragment extends RestaurantListFragment {
    @Override
    protected void onActivityCreatedInternal() {
        Log.d(TAG, " :Modify :onActivityCreated");
    }
}
```

What you're doing here is delegating from `onActivityCreated()` to a new method `onActivityCreatedInternal()`, and in the subclass you are **not** calling `super.onActivityCreatedInternal()`.

This will allow you to both (a) satisfy the requirement that all Fragment subclasses call through to `super.onActivityCreated()` and (b) allow complete overriding of the behavior "inside" `onActivityCreated()` by overriding the method being delgated to.